# File upload error in MS Azure after custom domain was pointed to Azure server

Tags: assets, craft-pro, assetfilemodel

I am facing an issue with file uploads. I installed a new installation of Craft CMS on Microsoft Azure server. MS Azure assigns a default domain to your webapp like example.azurewebsites.net. 
So while the default domain was assigned, I uploaded few asset files (images) successfully.

Later we had a custom domain added to Azure like mydomain.org
Once the custom domain was mapped, I edited the SiteURL (in Settings -> General -> mydomain.org) to the custom domain.
Now I am unable to upload asset files.

The error log shown in the Craft CMS craft.log (from Server Info) is move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty (D:\serverpath\craft\app\assetsourcetypes\BaseAssetSourceType.php:170)

Can someone please help.

Comment: Are you defining the site URL with the siteUrl config setting in `config/general.php` by chance?

Comment: No, have defined the siteURL in the Craft cms admin -> settings -> general screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS support team helped to resolve the issue. I will post the steps to be followed.

1. In your CMS Admin, Under Assets source -> 
   File system path: images/
   URL: http://example.azurewebsites.net/images
   (Here the images directory is under public directory)
2. In Azure portal, Add the following App settings in Application setting of your App service:
   key: WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE 
   value: 0
3. Restart the Azure App service.